# html5 file input - how do I change the color of the file text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using an input type=file in a form, and after some javascript validation I'm changing the color to red if invalid and would like to change it back to black if valid.

However when I try to change it back to black, it stays red.  How can I change this text color?  Here is an screenshot example of the page after having used javascript to set the color back to black but the filename "2018-06-01-I...-3 cpds.csv" is still red:

[image: screenshot of file input where text is red after the input color has been set back to black]

Here is my code snippet:

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var dataFileInput = $("#dataFileInput");
    dataFileInput.css("color", "black");
    var dataFiles = dataFileInput[0].files
    console.log("dataFiles:");
    console.log(dataFiles);
    if (0 == dataFiles.length) {
        result = false;
        errorMessagesUl.append('<li style="color: red">please select one or more data files</li>')
        dataFileInput.css("color", "red");
    }
}
</script>
...
<input type=file id=dataFileInput multiple="">
```

Comment: You can create a label and change the color. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947617/how-can-i-change-a-label-after-validate-a-file-size/50947936#50947936

Comment: Thank you but that didn't work.  If I surround my input in a label (as in your link) and then try to use the jQuery to change the color of that label it doesn't work - same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A work around - add a click handler to the file input element to change the color to black when it is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dataFileInput").click(function(evt) {
        $("#dataFileInput").css("color", "black");
    });
});
```